# How to handle exceptions on a microservice in Nestjs?

Tags: tcp, nestjs, microservices

I am new to microservices, and one thing I still haven't really understood is the pipeline for exceptions, from the microservice to the controller

- Suppose I have an API gateway and a microservice, using TCP as way of transport
- Suppose microservice has a error, say its some database error like trying to create a user with already existing email
- as far as I understand it here, you should throw a rpcexception here and the api gateway catches it
- but since a rpcexception only contains a message, no statuscode, how do i handle that on the api gateway?

adding onto that, since I have been messing around with cloud logging (logtail). if an error occurs on the microservice, should I log it both on the microservice and the api gateway?

Hoping someone can clarify this for me! thanks in advance

Comment: try avoiding rpcexception and use custom error handlers with exceptionfilter, and use validationpipe in both gateway and microservice. https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1